# Realm scheme description not identical on Simulator and Device

Tags: ios, realm

In our app we use a static realm, which we can load and update on runtime. To identify the correct version of the Realm scheme, we use a md5 hash of the realm scheme description. So if our schema changes we just need to supply a new version of the database and the app is able to find it. By this we can have multiple versions out at the same time, each being able to load or update its corresponding database.

This worked fine a long time until we discovered lately that the description of the realm scheme is not the same on a simulator and the device in some rare cases. We have about 35 Entities and the strange thing is that only one description differs in the order of the fields.

```
SomeEntity {
    telefon {
        type = bool;
        objectClassName = (null);
        linkOriginPropertyName = (null);
        indexed = NO;
        isPrimary = NO;
        optional = YES;
    }
    email {
        type = bool;
        objectClassName = (null);
        linkOriginPropertyName = (null);
        indexed = NO;
        isPrimary = NO;
        optional = YES;
    }
}
```

What differs? "telefon" and "email" are switched in order on the real device - what of course leads to a different md5 hash.

Shouldn't the description be identical on all devices?

What would be a distinct and reliable way to identify a realm scheme?

**Edit**
We use the same version of realm on both the devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Realm files track the versioning of their schema via a value called the `schemaVersion`. You can explicitly control which version of schema the Realm is at by incrementing the value in the `Configuration` object. Incrementing it will trigger a migration:

```
let config = Realm.Configuration( 
  schemaVersion: 1,
  migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in }
)
```

You can also check the current `schemaVersion` of a Realm file without opening it by calling the [`schemaVersionAtURL(_:encryptionKey:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Functions.html#/s:F10RealmSwift18schemaVersionAtURLFzTV10Foundation3URL13encryptionKeyGSqVS0_4Data__Vs6UInt64) function. This can let you choose what to do with a Realm file based on its schema version before opening it.

The `description` of the Realm schema is there for debugging purposes and was never intended  to be relied on as a part of an app's business logic.